# Expo linking fb post url scheme

Tags: react-native, facebook, share, expo-linking

Is there a working url scheme for posting on Facebook app (not opening in browser) from Expo app? I've read all about deep linking on Expo documentation, but whatever I type for `fb://` it only opens the app and does nothing, and I need to post some text. I've used `expo-linking` to share an image or text in Facebook Messenger and other apps (Sms, Twitter, WhatsApp) and it's working:

```
const openMessenger = async() => {
    try{
      await Linking.openURL(`fb-messenger://share/?link=${myLink}`);
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: No there is not.